# Querying large table with filter vs small table in database - any performance gain?

Tags: sql, database

I have a large table with 10 million records and is used for one of our existing applications. we are working on a new application wherein it requires only filtered result set of large table with 7000 records.

My question is will there be any performance gain going for a smaller table with 7000 records vs querying large table with filter condition(and it will joined to few other tables in the schema which are completely independant from existing application)? or should I avoid redundancy maintaining all the data in one table? This is the design in data warehouse. Please suggest!

Thank you!

Comment: A query on 7000 records will be a lot fast than a query on 10M records, but there are other factors to think about. 1) How often will you run a query? 2) Based on Q1, is running the query over 10M records going to be a significant burden on resources? 3) How current do the data need to be, presumable the 10M record table is being added to, so this requirement would be traded off against how often you would update the 7000 record table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For almost any database, using a sample table will be noticeably faster.  This is because reading the records will require loading fewer data pages.

In addition, if the base table is being updated, then a "snapshot" is isolated from page, table, and row locks that occur on the main table.  This is good from a performance perspective, but it means that the versions can get out-of-synch, which may be bad.

And, from a querying perspective, the statistics on the sample would be more accurate.  This helps the optimizer choose the best query plans.

I can think of two cases where performance might not improve significantly.  The first is if your database supports clustered indexes and the rows that you want are defined by a range of index keys (or a single key).  These will be "adjacent", so the clustered index would scan about the same number of pages.  There is a slight overhead for the actual index structure.

Similarly, if your records were so large that there was one record per data page, then the advantage of a second table would be less.  It would eliminate the index access overhead, but not reduce the number of reads.

None of these considerations say whether or not you should use a separate table.  You should test in your environment.  The overhead of managing a separate table (and there is a cost to creating and deleting it both in terms of performance and application complexity) may outweigh small performance gains.